# FFmpeg I-P frame command in golang

Tags: go, parsing, ffmpeg, frame

I have been using the command below to get a specific frame from the video and get it into a buffer.

```
func ReadFrameAsJpeg(inFileName string, frameNum int) []byte {
    // Returns specified frame as []byte
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    err := ffmpeg.Input(inFileName).
        Filter("select", ffmpeg.Args{fmt.Sprintf("gte(n,%d)", frameNum)}).
        Output("pipe:", ffmpeg.KwArgs{"vframes": 1, "format": "image2", "vcodec": "mjpeg"}).
        WithOutput(buf, os.Stdout).Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
```

While getting a specific frame according to a FrameNum, I want to also check which type of frame it is. Like using "pict_type" to get that information. I tried using a filter to get the frame type below, but it showed "error parsing the argument". It should give the output with the "pict_type = P" or "pict_type = I"

```
Filter("select", ffmpeg.Args{fmt.Sprintf("eq(n,%d),showinfo", frameNum)}).
```

I am trying to implement the following command

```
$ ffmpeg -hide_banner -i INPUT.mp4 -filter:v "select=eq('n,3344'),showinfo" -frames:v 1 -map 0:v:0 -f null -
```

Comment: you need to escape the comma in the filter expression. Specifically, `"gte(n\\,%d)"` (or how many ever backslashes you need to send one backslash to the ffmpeg parser) (I'm assuming the wrapper library that you are using doesn't take care of this)

Comment: The code mentioned above works perfectly, it is just that I want to check the 'pict_type' as well while running that filter or implement it in a new filter. Pict_type gives "PICT_TYPE_I"or "PICT_TYPE_B" or "PICT_TYPE_P"

Comment: I think I got what you are asking for. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying `showinfo` as a part of `select` filter options, instead of defining 2 different filters. Assuming that you are using [this library](https://github.com/u2takey/ffmpeg-go), you need to do something like this:

```golang
ffmpeg.Input(inFileName)
  .Filter("select", ffmpeg.Args{fmt.Sprintf("eq(n,%d)", frameNum)})
  .Filter("showinfo")
  .Output(...)...
```

I'm not familiar with go language so there maybe a syntax issue that you may need to sort out.

Edit:
Yes it is right it should be a different filter.
For golang it works using,

```
Filter("select", ffmpeg.Args{fmt.Sprintf("gte(n,%d)", frameNum)}).
Filter("showinfo", ffmpeg.Args{"TRUE"})
```